# Nice font not working when http to https - SSL Issue

Tags: multisite, redirect, https, http

I have two questions here about SSL actually. This is my very first time using ssl for website.

**1st question:**
I have recently purchased an `ssl` for my websites. I have a `nice font` for my website which is rendering correctly when the site is running on `http`. But, i'm not sure why the nice font not working after i switched my site to `https`.

Anything do i need to do to make it work?

**2nd question:**
My website was built with `multisite` enabled during installation. Now, i have created 3 more website under sub domain. Now, the ssl is activated for my main site and all the sub sites. I would like to ask, how to redirect the main site url to `https` from `http`? And, all the sub sites to `https` from `http`?

Here goes the nice font coding

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  src: local('Open Sans Condensed Bold'), local('OpenSans-CondensedBold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v6/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xOV5Bi3AvzDkLbMkkmS9JR4.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: I believe you should separate your questions.

Are you sure you wish to redirect and not actually move? Do the sites currently work fine over https, just existing external links break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the http to https in there:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  src: local('Open Sans Condensed Bold'), local('OpenSans-CondensedBold'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensanscondensed/v6/gk5FxslNkTTHtojXrkp-xOV5Bi3AvzDkLbMkkmS9JR4.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Google sends them over https too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026809/google-web-fonts-on-https-pages-on-chrome this sounds like a better solution, just remove the protocol.

Comment: Wasn't sure protocol flexible URLs were allowed or not in CSS.

Comment: I think they are, a url is url everywhere it is.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, Yes! It worked after i have changed to `https` from `http`. Thanks for the answer! :)